# How to create a collection of objects with custom properties as the unique ID - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, nosql

I am trying to make a collection of objects, where each property is an unique identifier. Example:

```
var Collection = {
       id1: {name: 'John', city: 'Boston'}
       id2: {name: 'Elvis', city: 'Philadelphia right?'}
}
```

Now, the property names `id1` and `id2` should be created when adding a new element, as I am generating a unique id (`Math.random()`).

I have tried:

```
var Collections = {};
var idtemp = 'id'+Math.random();
Collections[idtemp] = {name: 'Ben', city: 'New York'}
```

but that does not work (nothing happens, no console output).

Any thoughts? Is this also the way to go or should I consider arrays of objects? Problem is, I don't like array of objects as it requires taking a for-loop to find an element.

Comment: You are very sharp! Yeah I am using localstorage and am trying to setup the back-end in a JSON style format. Actually, that was the issue - there was a wrong calibration in the localstorage which I fixed now.  Do you know any databases for localstorage or is using a JSON style format sufficient?

Comment: @AMG reading your comment, is your question still relevant?

Comment: No. I gave already answer to my own question. How should I proceed?